# custom script to migrate d5 to d7

Tags: migrations

can any one suggest the custom script to migrate the contents,views and content types from D5 to D7. We already tried with normal conversion process like d5=>d6=>d7 but we facing many errors and contents and views are not imported correctly.

Comment: If you expect that everything works out of the bugs you should remove your illusion. updates are non-trivial in drupal. If there would be such a script everyone would have it.

Comment: It's a unicorn, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

This should help: [Direct Drupal 5 to Drupal 7 Migration in 24hrs](http://quicksketch.org/node/5739).

So, rebuild the views and content types on the Drupal 7 site, then use a custom script (like the one provided in the article, or one you write yourself), or the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module to move the data.