# Convert a Drupal 5 site to Drupal 7

Tags: migrations

We have a site with the configuration of Drupal 5, and we need to convert content, content types, views, and everything into Drupal 7. We have already tried with the normal conversion process like D5 => D6 => D7, but we are facing many errors; content and views are not imported correctly.

Is there any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [export /import the content types and views from D5 to D7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/export-import-the-content-types-and-views-from-d5-to-d7) asked from the same user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom script to migrate d5 to d7](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9200/custom-script-to-migrate-d5-to-d7).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/migration-from-drupal-5-to-7

Answer (score 3):

From what I've read, going from D5 -> D6 -> D7 can be a pretty involved task.

These two pages suggest you may want to start with a clean install of D7, recreating your content types and  Views, then using [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module or a custom script to migrate the content/users. (The migration path from CCK to the Drupal 7 Fields is discussed here: http://drupal.org/node/1144136.)

- http://drupal.org/upgrade
- http://quicksketch.org/node/5739

I don't know how complex your setup is (how many Views, content types, and modules you have), but it's probably the case you are going to need a fair amount of work to bring your site into Drupal 7.

- The related question is https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/migration-from-drupal-5-to-7.